# I want to lock account not using IP Address. Laravel

Tags: laravel

Laravel has an account lock function.
But it is based on IP address.
It can also be disguised.
Therefore, I want to lock the account itself regardless of the difference in IP address

How can I do?

Comment: Laravel has an account lock based on IP? That's news to me, can you please provide more detail?

Comment: @apokryfos vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ThrottlesLogins.php throttleKey()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a package for this :)

You can block users, emails, ip addresses, domain names, cities, states, countries, continents, and regions from using your application, logging in, or registering.

https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-blocker

Answer (score 1):

Throttling is not locking so even if you changed it to not be bound to the IP the account will be able to log in again after waiting for some time.

If this is what you want to do then you can override the `throttleKey` function to use a key not based on IP. If you want to completely ban someone then you can also probably override the `decayMinutes` to a value of say 100 years.

For example in your normal auth controller:

```
class class LoginController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    // ...

    public $decayMinutes = 52560000; // 100 years

    protected function throttleKey(Request $request)
    {
        return Str::lower($request->input($this->username())); // No IP here now
    }

}
```

Note: Since the rate limiter stores the values in the cache, then clearing the cache will also clear the blocked users. If you want a more permanent solution you can probably add a flag on the user entry in the database indicating that the user is blocked. This is just a quick and dirty solution to get things working for you quickly.

As another note: Not blocking by IP means you're locking someone out if someone else tries to hack into their account. This might be a bit infuriating for your users, which is also something to consider.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I’ll use this method